# Como executar query em C# para controle de solicitação

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server

Sou novo em programação e preciso acrescentar algumas funcionalidade em uma aplicação C# asp.net. Uma delas é um controle que impede o usuário de prosseguir com a solicitação caso ele tenha alguma pendência no sistema. Vou descrever o passo a passo.

Minha view

```
@using Integracao.ImpressoRequests.Model.Entities.ImpressoRequest
@model Request
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Requisição";
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

    ...

    @foreach (RequestItem item in Model.Items)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Usuario.Nome)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Date)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Unidade.Nome)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.ResultCenter.Nome)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
<div class="formfooter">

    <input type="button" value="Gerar pedido" onclick="window.open('@Url.Action("ProcessRequest", new { requestId = Model.Id })','_blank');window.location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Home")'" /></div>
```

Controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ProcessRequest(int requestId)
    {
        Request request = _data.Requests.GetByID(requestId);
        if (request.Processed)
            return RedirectToAction("PrintRequest", new { requestId = request });
        foreach (RequestItem item in request.Items.OrderBy(x => x.Usuario_Id))
        {
            AssignImpressos assignIItems = new AssignImpressos(item.Id);
            assignIItems.Assign();
        }
        request.Processed = true;
        _data.Save();
        return RedirectToAction("PrintRequest", new { requestId = request.Id });
    }
```

Model

```
    public Request()
    {
        Date = DateTime.Now;
        UsedItems = new List<Impresso>();
        RequestsHistory = new List<RequestHistory>();
        Items = new List<RequestItem>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }

    public string Justification { get; set; }

    public string Usuario_Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Impresso> UsedItems { get; set; }

    Model Impresso

        public class Impresso : IEntity
{
    public Impresso()
    {
        RequestsHistory = new List<RequestHistory>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int Code { get; set; }

    public string Purpose { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Data_Controle { get; set; }

    public decimal AdjustedValue { get; set; }

    public int Status { get; set; }
    public ItemStatus EnumeratedStatus
    {
        get { return (ItemStatus)Status; }
        set { Status = (int)value; }
    }        
    public string Note { get; set; }

    public string Usuario_Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; }

    public int? Request_Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Request Request { get; set; }

    public string Unidade_Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Unidade Unidade { get; set; }

    public string ResultCenter_Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ResultCenter ResultCenter { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<RequestHistory> RequestsHistory { get; set; }

    object IEntity.Id
    {
        get { return Id; }
        set { Id = (int)value; }
    }
}
```

O que eu preciso é o seguinte: Ao usuário clicar em 'Gerar Pedido' na view, na minha classe controller preciso varrer a tabela Pedido no banco procurando se aquele usuário já autenticado pelo sistema possui na tabela Impresso o campo 'Data_Controle' null ou o Status = 1. Caso positivo, o sistema deve impedir o prosseguimento disparando um alerta com a informação. Caso seja falso, o programa continua e gera a solicitação normalmente. 
A pergunta é: Eu sei como fazer um select no banco para buscar isso mas qual a sintaxe no c# de acordo com o meu código para fazer esse controle? Pensei em query porque mexo com banco de dados e a lógica é mais clara pra mim, ou se não por query, qual seria a melhor maneira de conseguir isso em lógica de programação mesmo? Obrigado

**Edit**

```
        private string GetUser()
    {
        string userId = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            string id = User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1];
            Usuario _currentUsuario = _data.Usuario.GetByID(id);
            userId = _currentUsuario.Id;
            ViewBag.UserName = _currentUsuario.Name;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("UserName", ex.Message);
        }
        return userId;
    }
```

Comment: Você quer que esse aviso apareça na tela como?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez pode ser um alert ou messagebox simples... O importante é travar o usuário e voltar a tela inicial quando ele der o ok de ciente de não poder solicitar...

Answer (score 2):

Você pode criar um ActionFilterAttribute para isto:

```
public class VerificarPendencia : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // Assumindo que você possui um ICollection<Impresso> Impressos para a entidade Usuario, e que esta coleção está populada ao obter o Usuario.
        if (_data.Usuarios.GetByID(GetUser()).Impressos.Any(x => x.Data_Controlle == null && x.Status == 1))
        {
           // Açoes...
        } 
    }
}
```

Pesquise um pouco sobre o ActionFilterAttribute para saber os métodos que você pode utilizar. E então você só precisa decorar a Action com este atributo:

```
[VerificarPendencia]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ProcessRequest(int requestId)
```

Todas as Actions decoradas com este atributo (se preferir, pode decorar o Controller inteiro) agora passam pelos métodos nela criados, como o OnResultExecuting, OnActionExecuted, etc...

Comment: Acredito que a resposta seria mais útil se a solução fornecesse os passos para a pesquisa, não pedir pro autor da pergunta pesquisar.

Comment: @EuripedesLeal dei uma pesquisada sobre esse método e pelo que vi ele pode ser uma alternativa sim. Porém minha dificuldade maior está justamente no "// aqui você faz o processo".

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez pode me dar um exemplo de implementação dessa resposta do Euripedes para eu me basear ou outra resposta que também julgue que me atenda?

Comment: Olha, não sou muito fã dessa abordagem de `ActionFilters` porque a validação de dados deve ser feita 1) No Model, ou 2) No Controller, quando envolve dados entre dois ou mais Models, o que é seu caso, mas é uma questão mais pessoal. Vou colocar duas maneiras de fazer, aí você elege qual a melhor.

Comment: ótimo :) obrigado

Comment: @PFVictor entendo. Pelo que vi nas respostas, você pode usar "_data.Usuarios.GetByID(GetUser()).Impressos.Any(x => x.Data_Controlle == null && x.Status == 1", eu alterei a resposta.

Comment: Obrigado @EuripedesLeal!

Answer (score 1):

O código está bem próximo do que você precisa. Imagino que `ProcessRequest` seja aquele código mais pra cima, então eu faria o seguinte:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ProcessRequest(int requestId)
{
    // Estou supondo que aqui você carregue seu usuário dentro de um objeto 'Usuario'
    // var usuario = contexto.Usuarios.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Nome == User.Identity.UserName);
    var usuario = _data.Usuarios.GetByID(GetUser());

    if (contexto.Impresso.Any(i => i.Usuario_Id == usuario.Usuario_Id && (i.Data_Controle == null || i.Status == 1))) {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Coloque aqui a mensagem que explica porque o sistema não pode continuar");
        return View();
    }

    Request request = _data.Requests.GetByID(requestId);

    if (request.Processed)
        return RedirectToAction("PrintRequest", new { requestId = request });

    foreach (RequestItem item in request.Items.OrderBy(x => x.Usuario_Id))
    {
        AssignImpressos assignIItems = new AssignImpressos(item.Id);
        assignIItems.Assign();
    }

    request.Processed = true;
    _data.Save();
    return RedirectToAction("PrintRequest", new { requestId = request.Id });
}
```

Comment: eu tenho dentro do mesmo controller do ProcessRequest uma classe GetUser que identifca o usuário, a qual editei na pergunta. Nesse caso, a primeira linha eu trocaria por `var usuario = _data.Usuarios.GetByID(GetUser()); ` certo?

Comment: @PFVictor Isso. Aliás, fique à vontade pra editar minha resposta, se quiser.

Comment: Deu certo @CiganoMorrisonMendez. Obrigado mais uma vez.